# How to fix img src in c# email sender

Tags: c#, email, html-email

I'm trying to send a email through c# and local everything works fine. But when I send through my published application the e-mail that I received comes without the src value of the  tag.

```
private async Task SendActivationMail(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            string code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

            var usuarioNome = user.DisplayName;

            // Using protocol param will force creation of an absolut url. We
            // don't want to send a relative URL by e-mail.
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action(
              "ResetPassword",
              "Account",
              new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
              protocol: Request.Scheme);

            string botao = _emailSender.MontarBotao(
                    nome: "ATIVAR",
                    url: callbackUrl);

            string template = _emailSender.MontarTemplate(
                titulo: "Test",
                subtitulo: "Example!",
                nomeUsuario: usuarioNome,
                corpo: "O software exclusivo de gerenciamento do seu processo permite a você:",
                templateBotao: botao,
                rodape: "<p><b>IMPORTANTE:</b> Este email de ativação terá validade de 24 horas.</a></p>" +
                "<p>Você está recebendo este email porque foi cadastrado por um administrador no Sistema Example.</p>");

            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(user.Email, "[ATIVAÇÃO] - Seja bem-vindo ao sistema exclusivo da example!", template);
        }
```

Below I show a portion of the html just to show the image tag. This portion is part of the returned html of MontarTemplate method

```
return $@"
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td class=""Header-left Target"" style=""background-color: #fff;border: 0;border-collapse: collapse;margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;font-size: 0;line-height: 0px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;background-size: 100% 100%;border-top-left-radius: 5px;"" align=""right"" height=""156"" valign=""bottom"" width=""252"">
                <img src=""http://tempus.digital/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/tempus-white.png"" alt=""Example"" width=""600""></td></tr></tbody></table>
            <table class=""Section Title"" width=""100%"" style=""border: 0;border-collapse: collapse;margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: #ffffff;"">
```

I expect the e-mail to show the image, but the e-mail comes without the image.

`<IMG alt="Example" src="" width=600>`

Comment: I don't think this is the code generating your email, or please provide the actual results.

Comment: Edited with more information

Comment: Do you think it could be the email client removing the data-source because the url is not secure, I am aware of outlook doing it. Did you try to look into it?

Comment: I tried to put on a HTTPS and look through gmail and outlook but both does not show the value of image tag.

Comment: The source of the image is opened and closed before the image url, same for alt and width. Fix up those and try again?

Comment: Thank you guys. Azure needs the image published in a blob storage. Then I reference the path url from azure and everything works fine.